# reopen a closed WPF on a microsoft outlook addin c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, outlook, add-in

i've a WPF openned from a button in the ribbon of Microsoft Outlook, for an addin i'm developing.

```
private void _HandlerUserSettings(Office.CommandBarButton ctrl, ref bool cancel)
{
    var windowUserSettings = new WpfUserSettings();
    windowUserSettings.Show();
}
```

if i close the WPF from its close button, if i click again the button to handle the show of the window, it doesn't work.
i guess the close action does something more than a simple Hide, so my goal is to override the closing action. i tried to work on *Closing* method *WpfUserSettings_Window_Closing* of my xaml window:

```
<Window x:Class="TrainingForgeOutlookAddin.View.WpfUserSettings"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        d:DesignHeight="350" d:DesignWidth="700" Title="User Settings"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Loaded="WpfUserSettings_OnLoaded"
        Closing="WpfUserSettings_Window_Closing">
 ....
</Window>
```

do you have any suggestions or howto to read, that i didn't find?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the close function will destroy the window as you cannot call

```
 window.Show()
```

multiple times. This means that all the data in the window has been lost. This makes sense, since a Window is just like your normal window that hosts the root of your application. The way to do this, is to simply create a whole new window before calling .Show(). However, this creates the issue that your data is not saved. Once your open your new window, it will be blank again. While this is not quite part of your question, I think some might find this useful.

For this you will need to make the two Windows talk to each other in order to save data. The parent will hold onto the child's data and then give it to the newly created window to repopulate.

Some people prefer delegates, I prefer to use interfaces for this.

Define a simple interface. This sets up the relationship between the child and the parent window and allows the child to inform it's closing and give it's data back for safe keeping.

```
public interface IParentWindow
{
    void ChildClosed(SomeData data);
}
```

this will inform the parent window that the child has been closed and now the window can hold on to the data until the window is opened again.

Assign this to the parent window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IParentWindow
```

this will force you to implement the ChildClosed function. Before we do this, you will notice that I have defined SomeData. This can be anything you like as long as both windows use this to send data back and forth.

For me, the implementation of SomeData looks like this:

```
public struct SomeData
{
    public string name;
    public string email;
}
```

We can debate on why I made this a struct, but that is besides the point. You can make this a class if you would like.

Next, implement the child closed function. For this, create a SomeData object in your parent class scope:

```
 SomeData lastWindowData;
```

And this function can how tell the parent to hold on to it's data

```
 public void ChildClosed(SomeData data)
 {
     lastWindowData.email = data.email;
     lastWindowData.name = data.name;
 }
```

Ok, before we move onto the child window, we have to implement the opening of the window. Since, as I have found (please tell me there is another way around this?), that the Window cannot be reopened once closed. This means that we have to make a whole new window. Put this in your event, whichever opens the window:

```
 childWindow = new ChildWindow(lastWindowData, this);
 childWindow.Show();
```

as you will notice, the window takes the data and "this", which is our parent window. It does this so that it is able to call back to the parent window before being closed and allow the parent window to save the data.

Lets move onto the child window.

Modify the child window's constructor to accept a SomeData and an IParentWindow object. Looking back, the IParentWindow is the window which is opening the child.

```
  public ChildWindow(SomeData data, IParentWindow parent)
```

Now we get to save the data passed from the parent!

Define a data holder for your window which is the some SomeData object (inside the child window class)

```
  SomeData myData;
```

and in the constructor

```
  myData.email = data.email;
  myData.name = data.name;
```

so we can repopulate everything. You can figure out the re population part for yourselves. This way, the window has now received the data of the previously closed child window and we can restore it as though it's the previous window!

When you do something in the window (could be anything, anywhere), you can mutate your data. Say I assign a name and email:

```
  myData.email = "gordon@freeman.com";
  myData.name = "Gordon Freeman";
```

Finally but not least, once we close the child window, we can inform the parent window that the child is being closed and we can give it the newly updated data to save once again!

```
  protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
  {
      parent.ChildClosed(myData);
      base.OnClosed(e);
  }
```

rinse and repeat!

NOTE; For the first open, before you have any saved data, you can pass in an object with null variables. You can then, in the child window, figure out whether you need to update the UI or not based on this.

Comment: Hi @serguei-fedorov, it's not so clear to me where should I put `public ChildWindow(SomeData data, IParentWindow parent)` . You were talking about the *window* constructor, and in my _WPF scenario_ this is my constructor `public WpfUserSettings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }` but I don't know how to manage it with your suggestions.

Comment: You have to modify the child windows constructor to take those variables. This would be public WpfUserSettings(Some data, IParentWindow) remember the SomeData object should be defined by you. I guess the question that I have to ask, is do you want to save data when the window closes and reopens again? If not you an discard the data object. You will, as far as I know, need to interface in order to tell the parent window that the child is closed (and set a bool so that it doesn't open it again). This is IParentWindow, which in my example gets passed in with the constructor as "this".

Comment: I can post a second answer for you if you want me to cut down the answer specifically to your scenario.